# LM2940CT-12 output measuring 9.6V when relay used

Tags: voltage-regulator, power-electronics, battery-operated, 12v

So I've got a 12V pump, and a car battery, and I'm trying to regulate the 12-14V from the car battery to 12V output.

When using just the LM2940CT-12, it outputs 12V on the dot.
But when I use an Arduino to switch a relay, which then closes the circuit from the LM2940 to the pump to GND, it measures 9.6V across the pump terminals.

What is going on?

[image]

Fan Specification is "DC 12V 3.6W",
so I suppose
I = P/V = 3.333A ?
R = P/I^2 = 3.6/11.11 = 0.32 ohms?
This looks wrong.  It's been a while.

Pump Specification is "DC 12V 1.5A"

hmm ah.  So the LM2940 isn't meant to handle > 1  amps... i see...

Comment: Does your pump take more than 1A? Is the relay a SSR or a Mechanical Relay? Do you have an inrush limiter? Would you please post a schematic along with all relevant electrical material?

Comment: What is the voltage at the input to the LM2940 when the pump is on?  A schematic of your circuit might be helpful in diagnosing the problem...

Comment: Plus, how long and what gauge are the wires to the pump? If you're attempting to run the pump remotely, you have to take the wiring's voltage drop into account.

Comment: Ok I've simplified the example, using just a fan...  Battery measures 12.5V.  LM2940CT output measures 11.75V.  When I put a fan from the LM2940CT output to GND, the voltage over the fan measures 10.7V.  

The wires are about 20cm of 24 gauge or so.  Do you think my battery just needs to be charged up to 14V?

Comment: It's just a bit weird.  This chip is meant to regulate 12V, which it does without any load.  But as soon as I add a load, the voltage over the load drops by only 10V or so.

Comment: POST A SCHEMATIC. We can't see your circuit. Do you have a capacitor? If so what value? What Fan are you using? what current does it draw? Have you tested with a standard resistor and measured the resistance of it before inserting it into the circuit?

Comment: No input cap, are you heatsinking? And 12.5V no load voltage, but what is the voltage and current draw if you connect the pump or fan directly? The battery may not be good, or the voltage drop **under load** is bringing the Regulator below it's minimum drop out. It has 0.5 to 1 volt drop out at 1 Amp max load.

Comment: Ah, yeah it looks like the pump pulls 1.5A.  Which the chip doesn't handle.  Ehhh.  Ok. That's probably it.  Hmm do you know any better 12V LDO chip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three main issue.

1. Battery voltage under load. Any battery will see a drop in voltage when a load is applied. It's worse on smaller cells with high esr, but it happens even in bigger batteries. The true voltage of the battery can only be known when you measure it under load.
2. The regulator has a minimum input voltage to output voltage difference. This is called a drop out voltage. If Vin - Vout is less than the drop out, it will not regulate properly. This needs to be under load! **The LM2940 will have a drop out of 0.5V to 1V at its max current**

1 & 2 is why the fan is dropping the voltage down.

3. The max current of the regulator is being exceeded. **The LM2940 has a max of 1 Amp**. This will cause a higher drop out, heat issues and regulation problems.

1, 2, and 3 is why the pump is bringing the voltage down to 9 volts.

Also, not sure if you are heat sinking the regulator, and a input capacitor is always helpful.

Comment: When I run the pump directly off the battery, it's pretty close to 12V, which is why I've been keeping the battery undercharged.

But yeah I think the 1A max is definitely an issue :(